# ANTLR4 grammar not behaving as expected

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

I have some data required to be parsed. I am using ANTLR4 tool to auto generate java parsers and lexers, that I can use to form a structured data from the input data given below
Grammar:

```
grammar SUBDATA;
subdata:
    data+;
data:
    array;
array:
    '[' obj (',' obj)* ']';
intarray:
    '[' number (',' number)* ']';
number:
    INT;
obj:
    '{' pair (',' pair)* '}';
pair:
    key '=' value;
key:
    WORD;
value:
    INT | WORD | intarray;
WORD:
    [A-Za-z0-9]+;
INT:
    [0-9]+;
WS:
    [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

Test Input Data:

```
[
    {OmedaDemographicType=1, OmedaDemographicId=100, OmedaDemographicValue=4}, 
    {OmedaDemographicType=1, OmedaDemographicId=101, OmedaDemographicValue=26}, 
    {
        OmedaDemographicType=2, OmedaDemographicId=102, OmedaDemographicValue=[16,34]
    }
]
```

Ouput:

```
line 5:79 mismatched input '16' expecting INT
line 5:82 mismatched input '34' expecting INT
```

[image: GUI Tree O/P]

Parser is failing although I have the integer value at the above expected position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made the classic mistake of not ordering your lexer rules properly. You should read and understand the [priority rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267981/3764814) and their consequences.

In your case, `INT` will *never* be able to match since the `WORD` rule can match everything the `INT` rule can, and it's defined first in the grammar. These `16` and `32` from the example are `WORD`s.

You should remove the ambiguity by not allowing a word to start with a digit:

```
WORD:
    [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]*;
INT:
    [0-9]+;
```

Or by swapping the order of the rules:

```
INT:
    [0-9]+;
WORD:
    [A-Za-z0-9]+;
```

In this case, you can't have words that are fully numeric, but they will still be able to start with a number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it is the order of lexor tokens within the parser rule which matters the match. I thought more in the regex way ignoring the fact that, first lexical tokens are generated before matching the parser rule itself

Comment: In addition to Lucas' answer: if you see unexpected behavior in parsing always start solving them by looking at the tokens the lexer produced. This would have shown you that the token sequence was different from by you expected.